# Trying to get background color

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When I'm trying to get bgcolor using xpath I'm not getting the actual color.

**HTML Code**

```
   <div class="__title">Preferred 2:1 </div>
```

**Selenium code:**

```
String bgColor=New_AEMLocators.marketingBanner.getCssValue("background-color");
```

When I'm trying to print the bgColor,it printing rgba(0,0,0,0)
But my bgcolor is white.

The text "**Preferred 2:1**" is in black color. Somehow it's printing that in the console.

Please help me in getting the exact bg color.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS attribute for the text color is simply "color", not bgcolor.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_color.asp

Inspect the "___titie" class to double check it.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this code for Google.ca and it worked:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.ca/")
String color = driver.findElement(By.id("gsr")).getCssValue("background-color");
System.out.println(color);
```

Output:

```
rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)
```